Trying to position something based on window/screen size rather than container size
I'm using Vue/nuxtjs, I'm trying to create a tooltip that shows when I hover over some images that are within a container. I want to tooltip to basically appear in the bottom right of the screen. The problem I am having is that since the imagine is in the container's, the positioning is relative to the container, and the containers' locations change.
Heres the best I could come up with.
handleMouseEnter(image, event) {
      const width  = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || 
      document.body.clientWidth;
      const height = window.innerHeight|| document.documentElement.clientHeight|| 
      document.body.clientHeight;
      var containxy = document.getElementsByClassName("object images")[0];
      var position = containxy.getBoundingClientRect();
      var x = position.right;
      var y = position.bottom;

      this.tooltipStyle = {
        position: 'fixed',
        bottom: `${height - y}px`,
        right: `${width - x}px`,
        visibility: 'visible'
      };

Since the bottom and right are relative to the container, my thoughts are
Max width - container_max_x = right edge of the screen
Max height - container_max_y = bottom edge of the screen
But this is wrong, it gets closer to what I'm trying but its still off. I'm not sure what calculation would be better, or if theres another way entirely.

I realize I was thinking about this somewhat backwards, I needed negative values instead of positive.
so swapping  to
bottom: ${y - height }px,
right: ${x - width }px,
Got me closer to the ideal solution. Still wondering if theres a better way to approach this.

Wouldn't it make more sense to just position the button absolute directly via css and change size with media-queries? Maybe I didn't understand what exactly what is important to you in this case?

I tried that, Any tooltip I add is relative to the image container it spawned from,  regardless what position setting i change it to. I couldnt figure out how to ignore all the inherited properties so I went about it from another route.

I guess that's because the next tooltips parent element having a set position is part of image-container. Can you place the tooltip elsewhere in you DOM structure? Otherwise position: fixed; should position your element regardless where placed in DOM - did you try fixed values while set position: fixed;?

Yea, I tried both
.tooltip-wrapper {
position: absolute; //and fixed
bottom: 0px;
right: 0px;
This always places it somewhere within the container
The reason why the tooltip is located there is because theres other logic handled when I hover over the images. This is why i started going down the windows.innerheight route. Trying to make it relative to the screen and not the container.

You should not be using DOM selectors with Vue/Nuxt. Give a try to VueUse composables rather.

new to Vue in general, so I'll look that up, thanks
